# How to run IdentityServer3 as a Windows Service

Tags: windows-services, identityserver3

I have some experience with Windows Services and am just getting my feet wet with IdentityServer3. My current solution works fine in IISExpress but I can't get it to work in IIS. So, I thought it might be easier to host it in a Windows Service, but I have not been able to find any samples to get up and running. Has anyone taken this approach?

My first though is I will need to instantiate my IS3 Startup class in my OnStart method and then call the Configuration method to create my authentication server, but that method takes an IAppBuilder parameter and I don't know how to create this. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Jpaull, at initial times it was the case to me as well, its better to resolve the issue on IIS deployment, mostly certificate & host name issues are there. Do post that error and find that solution. In short even you can run IDS3 as a console application(sample is available in identityserver3 GIT). In long run its always better to host it in the IIS.

Comment: Just a final comment for anyone who comes here looking for an answer. I did end up going back and running IdentityServer in IIS. I never did fully resolve the problems I experienced with trying to run it in a Windows Service.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing something similar to this...

```
public partial class ServiceHost : ServiceBase
{
    private IDisposable _service;

    public ServiceHost()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Start(string[] args) { OnStart(args); }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        var options = new StartOptions("https://localhost:44331/");

        _service = WebApp.Start(options, Configuration);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _service?.Dispose();
    }

    private static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
            .UseInMemoryUsers(Users.Get())
            .UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
            .UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get());

        var idsrvOptions = new IdentityServerOptions
        {
            Factory = factory,
            SigningCertificate = Cert.Load(),
            AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions
            {
                // This is where we configure External Identity Providers
                IdentityProviders = ConfigureIdentityProviders
            }
        };

        app.UseIdentityServer(idsrvOptions);
    }

    private static void ConfigureIdentityProviders(IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I did something similar although now I am dealing with issues that have popped up inside of IdentityServer. I was waiting to post my own solution until I got it fully working. The one difference is that I called the WebApp.Start method without the Configuration parameter and the Configuration is still done inside the IdentityServer Startup class. I am curious if you got your solution fully working and tested out? It seems unlikely but maybe the way you did it would fix the issues I am seeing within IS.

Comment: @jpaull, yes my solution is working. The only real difference from what I posted above is that the Configuration, ConfigureIdentityProviders and WebApp.Start stuff is actually wrapped in another class that exposes a public static IDisposable Start method that accepts some custom parameters. I didn't post that because it seemed like too much detail.

Also, I am just using this method for development purposes, for production we would likely be using IIS (but I haven't tried it yet).